# How can I get YouTube channel name and views by a video link in Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I make an android app using YouTube video **embedded link** in Android studio. I get video thambnail using video link. But I can't views and YouTube channel name via link. I want to get YouTube video views and channel name from this link. Please help me.

I want to like this.

Comment: Presumably, you need to load the Web page from the link, then parse the HTML (perhaps using JSoup) to get the information that you want.